# JavaScript, what is this "variable.function(parameter)" notation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Write code so that console logs print out true.

`add(addValue)` should return a new arrays where `addValue` is added to each value of original array, 
i.e. `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`.

```js
var e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(e.add(5) == '[6,7,8,9,10]');

var d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(d.add(10) == '[11,12,13,14,15]');
```

Comment: Are you asking what objects are ?

Comment: The first example is possibly feasible. What is the logic for `console.log(d.add(10) == '[11,12,13,14,15]')` where `d` is `var d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`? How do we get `[11,12,13,14,15]` from `10`? Are you expecting the elements to be concatenated to original array? Or a new array returned consisting of only the created values?

Comment: I don't think you understand the task you have been given

Comment: I can't see how the title is at all related to the question! The question reads like you're testing us. If I knew there was going to be a test I wouldn't logged in to SO today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to add an `add()` method to `Array.prototype` *(which is generally a bad idea)*

```js
Array.prototype.add = function(n) {
    return JSON.stringify( this.map( k => k + n) );
}

var e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(e.add(5) == '[6,7,8,9,10]'); // true

var d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(d.add(10) == '[11,12,13,14,15]'); // true
```

Comment: Why does the method need to be added to `Array` prototype?

Comment: @guest271314 - because that's how it works. *(creating an array with shorthand [] is like `new Array`, which is an instance, which would use prototyped methods for things like this etc.)*

Comment: Re-read Question. OP does chain the method at code at Question

Comment: @guest271314 - I actually did reread the question, and it seems the OP wants those weirds conditions to return `true`, so ...

Comment: Was referencing self as to re-reading Question and conveying gathered the reason that you added the method to `Array` `.proptotype` at code at Answer

Comment: I think the question is mal-formed. It says *`add(addValue)` should return a new arrays [sic]*, yet in your solution it returns a string, and I can't see how any implementation of `add` that returns an array could ever make the `==` return `true`.

Comment: @torazaburo - true, I just read the first line *"Write code so that console logs print out true"* ...